# How to read/mount a .gz.dd image file?

Tags: compression, partitioning, decompression

I have a partition file (a .gz.dd file) that I need to read the files from. I'm new to Linux and I don't know how I can read/mount .dd files in Ubuntu. Would you guys tell me the procedure of reading the file? Thanks.

Comment: Is it gz.dd, or dd.gz? I'd expect the latter to be more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not a `.dd.gz` file?

Here's how you uncompress a gzipped file:

```
gunzip example.dd.gz
```

This should create a file named `example.dd` in your current working directory.

To mount a `dd` image file, create a directory, and mount the image to that directory:

```
$ mkdir exampledir/
$ mount -o loop example.dd exampledir/
```

You may need to specify more options to the `mount` command depending on what type of image your file is.

You can now view the files inside the image by browsing `exampledir/`.

Comment: It was a .gz.dd file. But I renamed it to a dd.gz file and did the procedure you explained and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Linux isn't so much about the file extensions, the `.dd` is merely for better readability. Meanwhile `.gz` is more seriously used for compressed files, so the file would more canonically be named `example.dd.gz`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **read the files on-the-fly** from your (gzip) compressed filesystem **without having to unpack it**, use `mksquasfs` and `dd` to create it in the first place.

You can also choose the compression with the `-comp` option of `mksquashfs`, e.g. gzip, lzo, xz etc.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75590/31673) on how to do it (backup/create image, mount one partition of a whole diskimage with the help of `kpartx`, etc.).

Comment: You can also consider [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1097391/910769).